# how can I make date fields come out in other languages in webform with drupal 7

Tags: webforms

using drupal 7 , and Webform 7.x-3.18 + 3-dev 
I need my date field to come out in spanish, mes/dia/ano

but it keeps on coming out with month/day/year

How can I fix this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed, I was logged in as an admin and had admin language set to english